# What is the mapping between PIL resize filters and their integer representations?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize an image using the Python package Pillow. The docs says that one of the parameters is `resample` and that it can be one of `PIL.Image.NEAREST`, `PIL.Image.BOX`, `PIL.Image.BILINEAR`, `PIL.Image.HAMMING`, `PIL.Image.BICUBIC` or `PIL.Image.LANCZOS`. Also the default filter is `PIL.Image.BICUBIC`.

The function declaration is `Image.resize(size, resample=3, box=None, reducing_gap=None)`. Notice how `resample` is an integer and not one of the above listed filters. Also, `3` does not correspond to the order that they give the filters in as it is supposed to be equivalent to `PIL.Image.BICUBIC`.

My question is, what are the integer representations of the filters? (Specifically looking for `PIL.Image.LANCZOS`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just [look at the source](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L164):

> ```
> NEAREST = NONE = 0
> BOX = 4
> BILINEAR = LINEAR = 2
> HAMMING = 5
> BICUBIC = CUBIC = 3
> LANCZOS = ANTIALIAS = 1
> ```

That said, you shouldn't ever need to use the integer directly, it'd be better to just refer to it as `Image.LANCZOS` anywhere you need to. i.e. the following two calls are equivalent, but the first one is much more readable:

```
Image.resize(size, resample=Image.LANCZOS)
Image.resize(size, resample=1)
```